# Load image from memory into VB6 PictureBox

Tags: vb6, picturebox

I'm not a VB6 developer so excuse me if I'm not making any sense.

If I have a VARIANT array of bytes containing an RGB array of image data, is it possible to get that data to be displayed in a PictureBox? The [PictureBox documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267232%28VS.60%29.aspx) suggests that the only acceptable sources are files.

Additionally, the image size and other image information is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PictureBox documentation lies. But unfortunately, it’s not pretty to create an `IPictureDisp` in memory. The following link may help you – unfortunately, it’s in German:

[How to create a picture from data in memory](http://www.activevb.de/tipps/vb6tipps/tipp0654.html)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better (i.e. faster) method, but you should look in to the PSet method of a picture box control.

[PSet method of picture box control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa230482%28VS.60%29.aspx)